# Do flat distance lasers exist?

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, laser, distance, light-sensor

In short, I want to create a flat laser plane that knows where it's being penetrated.

If flat distance lasers do not exist, what other options do? I considered using several *regular* distance lasers to make a "web" and accomplish the same goal like this:

[image: laser web]

but the regular lasers might be too bulky. I'm not sure if optical sensors are appropriate or accurate enough.

What is an alternative sensor or technology that may apply to this problem?

Comment: Can you put mirrors along two sides of the plane? If so, one laser beam will cover the whole plane.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what a spinning laser range finder does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing 2D [LIDAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) also known as RPLIDAR.

It does indeed exist. My robot vacuum uses it to navigate in my house. It's typically made of a spinning mirror and a single laser distance measurement unit.

[image]